# Update Table with Columns

Tags: sql, oledb

I have a table with the following columns, City, State, Zip, and Zone.
I want to update Zone with City - State - Zip with hyphens.

Is there a way to do this in SQL without grabbing all the records and iterating through the results and doing an update statement for each one?

Comment: If you're using this just to display `City-State-Zip`, then go for it, but if you're going to save the data in a table as `City-State-Zip` then it is a pretty bad idea.  It breaks the first rule of the first Normal Form - all columns must be atomic.

Comment: @Raj More, its a workaround because ESRI locator styles only return Zone, and client wants city, state, zip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table set zone = city + '-' + state + '-
 + Zip
```

Note if the datatypes are different you might need to do something like

```
update table set zone = cast(city as varchar(50)) + '-' + cast(state as varchar(50)) + '-
 + cast(Zip as varchar(50))
```

Comment: Note: TABLE  should be replaced with your table name.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do the following if I am not mistaken:

```
 UPDATE [Table_Name] Set Zone = (City + '-' + State + '-' + Zip)
```